# In .net, why can't values of intrinsic data types (such as DateTime) be null?

Tags: .net

First the history:

I found out DateTime data types cannot be null (Yes they can be nullable using the ? nullable declaration).

I was told this is because they are value types and placed on the stack (not on the heap).

I can understand why the stack is quicker and why value types need to (mostly) be placed on the stack, what I do not know is.

1. Is it true the real limitation of why a value type cannot be null is because the stack cannot handle null values?
2. If yes - Why? If No what is the real limitation.

I understand in .net we often don't care about exact memory allocation, yet it is important in performance applications to take the stack and heap into consideration, so I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Thanks in advance for your expertise on a difficult question.

EDIT: Another thing to add are nullable types hence placed on the heap or stack?

Comment: Forget about stack and heap. Seriously. In programming languages with fully automatic memory management ("managed"), the distinctions is [an implementation detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx). And if you're bent on thinking in these terms, at least seperate them from value/reference types. For instance: A value types doesn't *need* to be placed on the stack (in fact, they frequently aren't - see the linked article).

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) may interest you.  EDIT: Ninja'd :D

Comment: The title of the question is quite misleading - the title asks why null types can't be placed on the stack, but the body of the question asks why value types can't be null.

Comment: You are essentially asking why cant int's (and floats) be null. Sure they can be 0 but 0 is not null.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The heap and stack are not relevant. It is about Binary representation of values.

In a reference type, a zero binary representation means null, and other binary representations point to memory that contains the binary representation of the value.

In a value type, all binary representations, including zero, directly represent a particular value of the type. Value types cannot be null because there is no reserved binary representation that means null.

Comment: I hate to break it to you but `int?` or if you prefer Nullable<int> are indeed value types. And yet they support the `value = null` semantics. The binary representation of a value type has nothing to do with its semantics.

Comment: @Conrad, yes the Nullable<T> type itself defines representations for null. This a feature of that particular type and not of value types, like null values are a feature of reference types. I meant to answer the question of why in general value types cannot be null, not claim that you couldn't make a value type that could represent null.

Comment: @Conrad: You're wrong. `int?` has a special extra boolean field that indicates if it is null or not. `int` itself cannot be `null`, as there is no binary representation that indicates `null`.

Comment: @DeadMG `int? x= null;` works fine for me. Is that somehow different to you than `object x = null;`

Comment: @Conrad, .Net languages such as C# provide syntactic sugar for the Nullable<T> type to allow treating a Nullable<T> value with HasValue = false the same as a null reference type. However, having worked with MSIL code directly, I can tell you there are differences. Like if I want to load a null value for a reference type onto the stack, I can use "ldnull", but this does not work for Nullable<T>.

Comment: @JGWeissman sorry but your answer seems to indicate that the binary representation had something to do with why `int y= null;` doesn't work. I can't find any reference to support that can you?

Comment: To illustrate -- contrast the declarations *int x;* and *Integer X;* -- *x* can only be assigned an actual integer value between *int.MinValue* and *int.MaxValue* while *X* can be assigned to point to an object instance of an *Integer* object, or *null*.

Comment: @Conrad: Your question didn't ask about `int?`. It asked about `int`- effectively. An `int?` is larger than an `int`, as it has a special field to say if or not it is `null`. But a regular `int` has no `null` representation.

Comment: @Conrad, the point of talking about the "binary representation" is not that it is binary, but that it is a concrete low level thing that maps to the abstract high level values of the type, and I wanted to talk about the mapping.

Comment: @JGWeissman I guess my problem is that your answer is like saying cars don't fly because they don't have wings. And I'm saying they don't have wings because they're not meant to fly. Are non-nullable values types missing a null representation because they're value types or because they weren't meant to have nullable representations.

Comment: @JayElston I don't know what you're talking about. What language is the line `Integer X;` written in?

Comment: @Conrad, I would I agree that value types are not meant to have null values, and that I discussed more about *how* they don't have null values.

Comment: @JGWeissman ok so are you saying that the *how they don't have null values.* is the reason why "DateTime data types cannot be null"

Comment: @Conrad Integer is J#, in C#, you could say *System.Int32 X* instead. (I just finished a major project using Java, and unless I have an IDE to keep me in track, I mix syntax occasionally :-(

Comment: @JayElston um.. ok well in c# `System.Int32 X = null` doesn't compile. This isn't surprising since the C# Spec defines `int` as a simply an alias for System.Int32 (§4.1.4 Simple types). Does `Integer X = null;` work in J#?

Comment: @Conrad -- You are correct, in C#, Int32 is a struct, not a class, so it cannot be assigned null -- my bad... *Integer X = null;* compiles in J# as Integer is a class.

Answer (score 9):

> I found out DateTime data types cannot be null.

Your questions show that you have a pretty vague idea about how the whole system works. Let's start by picking apart what you mean by "DateTime data types cannot be null". I think what you mean here is that *the null literal cannot be implicitly converted to a value of DateTime*, and hence the null literal cannot be assigned to a variable of type DateTime.

That is:

```
DateTime d = null;
```

is not legal in C#. The null literal cannot be converted to DateTime, and so the initialization must fail at compile time.

> I was told this is because they are value types...

That is almost correct.

There are two kinds of value types: nullable value types and non-nullable value types. A nullable value type always has an "underlying" type. The underlying type is always a non-nullable value type.

It is always legal to implicitly convert a null literal to a nullable value type.

It is almost always illegal to implicitly convert a null literal to a non-nullable value type; the only time this happens is if someone creates a user-defined conversion operator on the non-nullable value type, and that user-defined conversion operator takes an argument to which the null literal is implicitly convertible.

> ... and placed on the stack (not on the heap).

This is completely and utterly wrong. Whomever told you that does not know what they are talking about. This makes no sense whatsoever. Whether a null literal is convertible to a type or not *at compile time* has nothing whatsoever to do with *where in memory the data is going to be stored at runtime.*

> I can understand why the stack is quicker and why value types need to (mostly) be placed on the stack

Then you are misunderstanding something. Values of value types need not be "mostly" placed on the stack.

Values of value type, and references to values of reference type, can *sometimes* be put on the **short term allocation pool** *when it is known at compile time that the lifetimes of the storage for those values is going to be short*. At runtime, that short term pool might be realized as stack locations or registers.

Whether data goes on the short term pool or the long term pool has nothing whatsoever to do with whether the data is a value of value type or a reference. They are not called the "value pool" and the "reference pool". They are the **short term** pool and the **long term** pool. Obviously which pool is used has only to do with the answer to the question "do we know ahead of time when we are going to be done using this value or reference?" If the answer is "yes", then the value or reference can go on the short term pool. If the answer is "no", then it has to go on the long term pool.

> Is it true the real limitation of why a value type cannot be null is because the stack cannot handle null values?

No, absolutely not. That makes no sense.

> What is the real limitation?

Let's look at an easier example than DateTime. Let's look at int. An int is four bytes, no more, no less. Suppose you have a variable of type int. It takes up four bytes. It might take up four bytes on the heap, four bytes on the stack, four bytes in a register -- doesn't matter. It is four bytes of storage, somewhere.

There are 2<sup>32</sup> possible values you can put into an integer: 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ... and so on. When you say:

```
int x = null;
```

what value do you suppose is going to go into those four bytes of storage?  There are only 2<sup>32</sup> possible values of four bytes, and they are already taken up by the numbers! You can't put six pigeons into five pigeonholes and still have only one pigeon in every pigeonhole. You can't put 2<sup>32</sup> + 1 values into 32 bits; you need at least 33 bits, and that's one more bit than we've got available.

Non-nullable value types cannot be null because *there are exactly as many possible values of a value type as their bits are capable of holding*. A distinct "null" value requires *one more* value than the maximum number the bits are capable of holding.

So how then do we do it with references? Simple; one of the references is reserved as "special"; the reference whose bits are all zero is set aside as never a valid reference. With ints we have a requirement that all 2<sup>32</sup> values be valid; with references implemented, say, as 32 bit pointers, we have no requirement whatsoever that all 2<sup>32</sup> possible pointers be valid; the vast majority of them are invalid.

Why don't we do that with value types? Because then:

```
int x = null;
```

is exactly the same as

```
int x = 0;
```

and it seems bogus to say that "null" just means "the zero of this type". Null should be a *distinct* value from every other value. (If you want to get the "zero" of a value type you can always say `default(T)` where T is the type. So `int x = default(int);` is the same as `int x = 0;`)

So how then do we do it with nullable value types? *We add more bits*. When you say:

```
int? x = null;
int? y = 123;
```

that is *exactly* the same as saying:

```
int x = 0;
bool xHasValue = false;
int y = 123;
bool yHasValue = true;
```

When you use a nullable value type, you are doing nothing more than passing around a non-nullable value type along with a flag that says whether it is null or not.

> I understand in .net we often don't care about exact memory allocation, yet it is important in performance applications to take the stack and heap into consideration, so I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

That is important in some scenarios, yes. But it has nothing whatsoever to do with the question of why the null literal cannot be assigned to a non-nullable value type.

> are nullable types hence placed on the heap or stack?

Values of nullable value types are placed wherever the compiler thinks best; they are not different from any other value of any other type.

If the compiler knows that a value will never be used again after a short period then the compiler generates code to place the value on the short-term storage. At runtime, this will be realized as a location on the stack or a register. If the compiler does not know that for sure then it generates code to place the value on the long-term storage heap.

Again, **where the storage for a value is located has nothing whatsoever to do with the type of that value**. It has only to do with the answer to the question "do I know for sure how long this value needs to hang around?" If the answer is "yes, and it is a short time", then the storage goes on the short-term pool. If the answer is "yes, and it is a long time" or "no, I don't know", then the storage goes on the long-term pool.

Comment: +1 But I'm still confused about what is the real limitation is. Other type systems have similar "simple" types that have the same defined storage and yet support null semantics. It seems to me that V1.0 CLI specification authors did not arbitrarily chose to define values types the way they did. Can you give any insight into that?

Comment: @ConradFrix: Implementations of other type systems manage to put six pigeons into five pigeonholes and end up with one pigeon per hole? I would love to see such a type system! I could do all kinds of great things with something that could violate basic laws of arithmetic with impunity! But sadly, there is no such beast. Implementations of type systems such as you describe either have hidden bits somewhere to track nullability -- as `Nullable<T>` does in .NET -- or they change the range of a value such that not all bit patterns refer to a legal value -- as IEEE floats do to define NaN values.

Comment: I don't doubt that they have hidden bits or a special bit pattern, but from my perspective that's an implementation detail. I doesn't give me insight into why `int x = null;` isn't allowed. Was it to expensive in terms of perf? Was it something the dev community didn't want? Was it to ensure some types would be blittable?

Comment: @ConradFrix: Here are your choices: (1) Make int a 32 bit value; reserve some of those values for null, making .NET int incompatible with many existing languages and thereby preventing platform adoptions, (2) Make a "32 bit" integer take up more than 32 bits; take an *enormous* performance hit every time you use an integer on a 32 bit machine; hardly anyone does that, right? or (3) make int non-nullable. Which would you choose?

Comment: @ConradFrix: Now, if we're talking about decisions made in the past that we regret, I regret this one. It is deeply unfortunate that we chose to make nullable reference types and non-nullable value types. History has shown that ideally the type system would make *how the value is copied* and *whether the type supports a missing value* orthogonal. It would have made my life easier had .NET had nullable value types **and non nullable reference types** from day one. But you can't do *everything* in v1, and remember, we didn't even have generics.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think that fairly neatly describes why nullable value types would have been a bad idea. It does make me wonder how the DB guys gets away it though. And I do remember that we didn't have generics. Sadly I didn't get to have Generics full-time until 8 weeks ago :P

Comment: @ConradFrix: The DB guys use extra bits too. Although, because databases store records rather than individual values, they (well, at least SQL Server's implementation) use a bitmask for each record (which groups all those extra bits needed into one place). A couple of links: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Table_and_Record_Structure http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/the-mystery-of-the-null-bitmap-mask/

Comment: @ligos. Nice but I'm also curious about how `Declare @int as integer; SET @int = null` works. It supposed to be [4 Bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) as well.

Comment: @ConradFrix: If the integer is nullable then there is an extra bit stored somewhere, I promise.

Comment: @EricLipper Oh, I don't doubt it, but I'd imagine the way that extra bit is stored could be different when the int is in a Table vs a variable in SQL Batch or Stored Procedure. I only mentioned it because the linked articles talked about null bitmaps in tables.

Comment: @ConradFrix: I Googled around but couldn't find any information about how a primitive scalar is actually stored in memory. The closest I can get is `SqlInt32` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint32.aspx). Reflector tells me it has has 2 fields: an `int` and a `bool`.